# Implicit animation fade-in is not working

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a UIView subclass which seeks to create a rounded rect overlay on top of one of its subviews.

When I use the code below, surely enough, a green rounded rect appears where I want it, but no matter what I do, I can't get it to fade in.

```
CALayer *parentLayer = [self layer];

// Create a new layer and configure it to be a rounded rect box overlay
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.position = [slider layer].position;
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kWTFSliderWidth, kWTFSliderHeight);
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
layer.borderWidth = 3.0;

// Add the layer with a fade in to the parent layer
[parentLayer addSublayer:layer];
```

Do I have to add `CABasicAnimation` manually to my parent layer object? Shouldn't a default instance already be present in `parentLayer`'s `action` dictionary?

Comment: For the record, yes, I have tried creating and committing a CATransaction layer scope with `addSublayer:` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `addSublayer:` call with this:

```
layer.hidden = YES;
[parentLayer addSublayer:layer];
[CATransaction flush];
layer.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: I'm glad that this works, of course, but why must it be this way? Shouldn't `begin`, `addSublayer`, and `commit` messages in that order be sufficient? Also, the docs (not surprisingly) have the following to say about `flush:` "However, you should attempt to avoid calling flush explicitly." Presumably for performance reasons.

Comment: The problem is your explicit transaction is nested inside the framework's implicit transaction.  The `flush` message commits the implicit transaction.  I think your new layer's state remains uncommitted until the outermost transaction is committed, and the framework only creates implicit transactions when you commit a property value that is different from the previously committed value.  I think I saw flush is some Apple sample code.  It may have also been mentioned in a WWDC video about Core Animation.  I highly recommend the WWDC videos.

Comment: Thanks again Rob for the clarification. Just another question: if I set a layer's hidden property to YES in order to fade it out, what is the proper way to remove it from the layer tree? I tried doing hidden = YES; followed by [layer removeFromSuperlayer];, but it seems that the code simply removes the layer right away. (This was actually the question that spawned the simpler one that I've asked you to answer in the SO thread.) Feel free to respond in a different answer entry.

Comment: Begin a `CATransaction`.  Set the transaction's completion block to send `removeFromSuperlayer` to the layer.  *Then* set the layer to hidden, then commit the transaction.